# Laravel Get releated records grom the same table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have table "categories" with following structure:
id | parent_id | title

As you see some categories has child categories.
And now i would like to get categories with child categories.

```
Category::childCategories()->get();
```

And in model categories I wrote this method.

```
public function childCategories(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->where('parent_id', $this->id);
    }
```

But I have following error:

> Call to undefined method
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::childCategories()

How should i do it?

Thank you.

Comment: It should be $this->hasMany

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try below code:

```
public function parentCategory() {
  return $this->belongsToOne(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function childCategories() {
  return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id')->orderBy('title', 'asc');
}
```